# What happened first in this sentence: "Journalists informed police who planted an undercover detective to trap Smith."

Tags: sentence-meaning, past-tense, time

> Journalists informed police who planted an undercover detective to trap Smith.

Is it possible to make out what happened first in the sentence?

Does it mean

> The police had planted an undercover detective to trap Smith, and then the journalists informed the police

or

> The journalist had informed the police, and then police planted an undercover detective to trap Smith

[collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/plant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The succession of actions is just the same as it is in the sentence. 1.The journalists informed the police.2. The police planted an undercover detective to trap Smith.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have a question: if every sentence looks like this way have the same succession of actions. or it just depend on the situation and logic?

Comment: It depends on the meaning inside the structure, I would say.

Answer (score -1):

I think the mostly likely explanation is that the journalists had planted the undercover detective. I think this because that if it were the police were to have planted the detective, then they wouldn't have to be informed about Smith.

In this case, it's *logic* instead of *grammar*.

Comment: How do you get that the journalists planted the undercover detective?  The sentence very clearly says "...police who planted".  If the journalists were doing the planting, what function does the phrase "informed police" serve?